# generic listener for buttons in a layout of android?

Tags: android

Scenario: I have three buttons defined in xml

```
<button android:id="@+id/firstbtn" 
    ...
/>
<button android:id="@+id/secbtn" 
    ...
/>
<button android:id="@+id/thirdbtn" 
    ...
/>
```

```
In Java one way to  listen to them is  
Button firstbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.firstbtn);  
    firstbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(View v) {  
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),   
                        "You have clicked first button",   
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
            }  
        });
```

for second btn , same code has to be repeated with different id ??
How can I make it generic enough that , it can listen to all buttons (say in for loop) and while handling I should be able to differentiate different btns. (may be get elements id)

Answer (score 8):

Instead of a huge set of `findViewById` calls I rather like to use the `onClick="methodName"` xml attribute. For example:

```
<LinearLayout ...>
  <Button android:text="1" onClick="onButtonClicked" clickable="true" />
  <Button android:text="2" onClick="onButtonClicked" clickable="true" />
  <Button android:text="3" onClick="onButtonClicked" clickable="true" />
  <Button android:text="4" onClick="onButtonClicked" clickable="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In the activity where the layout is shown just add a method

```
public void onButtonClicked(View v){
     // do whatever needs to be done. For example:
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((Button) v).getText() + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
}
```

You can also put the onClick and clickable attributes into the res/styles.xml file to save even more typing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="clickable_button" >
    <item name="android:onClick" >onButtonClicked</item>
    <item name="android:clickable" >true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Your layout is then simplified to

```
<LinearLayout ...>
  <Button android:text="1" style="@style/clickable_button" />
  <Button android:text="2" style="@style/clickable_button" />
  <Button android:text="3" style="@style/clickable_button" />
  <Button android:text="4" style="@style/clickable_button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6):

You need not repeat same code for all. You can try out a generic listener, like :

```
private OnClickListener mCorkyListener = new OnClickListener() { 
    public void Click(View v) {
            // do something
    } 
};
```

Then all you have to do is register all three buttons to use this mCorkyListener.
That is, inside onCreate(),

```
Button firstbtn  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.firstbtn); 
Button secondbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.secondbtn); 
Button thirdbtn  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.thirdbtn); 

firstbtn.setOnClickListener(mCorkyListener);
secondbtn.setOnClickListener(mCorkyListener);
thirdbtn.setOnClickListener(mCorkyListener);
```

Comment: No need to assign variables unless you're going to re-use them for something else:  `(Button)findViewById(R.id.firstbtn)).setOnClickListener(mCorkyListener);`

Comment: Ok so there is no way of getting button objects other than findViewBId(id) ?? I was thinking there might be a way to get all buttons in layout as array of button objects and I can loop through it and add a listener to it , It will avoid adding Java code each time I add button in XML.

Comment: I am not aware how to create your array of Buttons. Anyways, you can know which Button was clicked inside your mCorkyListener by using view.getId()

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412180/how-to-determine-which-button-pressed-on-android/) for code samples. You have to use `findViewById` to "find" you r buttons though.

Comment: It was partly helpful , I was wondering how to match View.getId() which is an integer with id name used in xml , understood after seeing the example. Thanks, but still searching for answer which is more generic. like get all btns as array of objects without using id and loop and attach listener to it.

Answer (score 0):

You Just Simply have to Follow these steps for making it easy...

You don't have to write new onClickListener for Every Button... Just Implement View.OnClickLister to your Activity/Fragment.. it will implement new Method called onClick() for handling onClick Events for Button,TextView etc.

1-Implement OnClickListener() in your Activity/Fragment

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    }
```

2-Implement onClick() method in your Activity/Fragment

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  // default method for handling onClick Events..
}
}
```

3-Implement OnClickListener() For Buttons

```
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

       Button one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.oneButton);
       one.setOnClickListener(this); // calling onClick() method
       Button two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.twoButton);
       two.setOnClickListener(this);
       Button three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.threeButton);
       three.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
```

4-Find Buttons By Id and Implement Your Code

```
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

       switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.oneButton:
        // do your code
        break;

        case R.id.twoButton:
        // do your code
        break;

         case R.id.threeButton:
        // do your code
        break;

        default:
        break;   }}
```